# How to get a platform-specific newline in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, newline, line-breaks, kotlin-multiplatform

I am seeking a function which returns a **platform-specific** newline string.
I'm aware of `System.lineSeparator()`, which is only available in **Kotlin/JVM**, but there's a need for a **multi-platform** equivalent.

I'm also aware of the **`expect`/`actual`** approach, but I'm searching for a shorter way. *(Maybe a function in the standard library?)*

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing in kotlin stdlib. Maybe, some part of [kotlin.text](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/) library might be used to create something similar manually. If you think that something like that would be useful, consider filing a feature request at https://kotl.in/issue.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
val newLine = "\n"
```

Comment: How is that platform-specific?  (That means it should return e.g.  `\n` on Unix-like OSs, `\r\n` on Windows, &c.)

Comment: If you write this in common module, it should get translated to correct value on respective platform. No need for expect-actual for this.

Comment: How would it get translated?

Comment: By the Kotlin native compiler when it builds native code for respective platform.